# parsing objects into methods

Tags: c#, object, methods

i'm trying to get this code to work.. i've been googling for over an hour already but i cant seem to get this code to work:
(i'm totally new to C#)

i think it has something to do with the method print. i get the following error:

type 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Voornaam' and no extension method 'Voornaam' of type 'object' could be found

```
// naam: Dylan Westra
// klas: i1b
// datum 07-09-2013
using System;

namespace les2
{

    public class client
    {
        public string Voornaam;
        public string Achternaam;
        public string Adres;
        public int Salaris;

        public client (string voornaam, string achternaam, string adres, int salaris)
        {
            Voornaam = voornaam;
            Achternaam = achternaam;
            Adres = adres;
            Salaris = salaris;
        }
        public void print (object obje)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (obje.Voornaam + " " + obje.Achternaam + " " + obje.Adres + " " + obje.Salaris);
        }

    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            client gegevens1 = new client("Dylan", "Westra", "Rozengracht 34", 1200);
            //client gegevens2 = new client("Rosa", "de Gruijter", "Rozengracht 34", 200);
            client.print(gegevens1);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Is there anything like an image (such as a box model in html) but then for classes, objects and methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `OOP` style, you should do something like this:

```
using System;

namespace les2
{

  public class client
  {
    public string Voornaam;
    public string Achternaam;
    public string Adres;
    public int Salaris;

    public client (string voornaam, string achternaam, string adres, int salaris)
    {
        Voornaam = voornaam;
        Achternaam = achternaam;
        Adres = adres;
        Salaris = salaris;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine (Voornaam + " " + Achternaam + " " + Adres + " " + Salaris);
    }
  }

  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        client gegevens1 = new client("Dylan", "Westra", "Rozengracht 34", 1200);
        gegevens1.print();
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: Remember to name the classes, properties and public methods with first letter capitalized, `Client` not `client`, `Print` not `print`. You may want to find more about `static member` and `instance member`.

Comment: I find this the best answer. in my opinion this answer explains the most and gives me a better perspective of objects. i'll accept it soon as answer

Answer (score 2):

```
public void print (object obje){
   Console.WriteLine (obje.Voornaam + " " + obje.Achternaam + " " + obje.Adres + " " + obje.Salaris);
}
```

Either change the method to `public void print (Client obje)`

or cast it first:

```
public void print (object obje) {
   obje = (Client) obje;
   // OR
   obje = obje as Client;
   Console.WriteLine (obje.Voornaam + " " + obje.Achternaam + " " + obje.Adres + " " + obje.Salaris);
}
```

The reason behind this is that you define your method to take an `Object` (which is every class's base class) as parameter, but this also means that you will only be able to access the methods defined in the `Object` class. If you want to use your methods defined in `Client`, you have to either define your method as such (first approach) or explicitly tell the compiler that you're going to use that parameter as an object of type `Client` (second approach).

That being said: considering `Print()` is defined in the `Client` class, you can just omit the parameter and directly access the instance members.

Resulting in this:

```
public void Print() {
 Console.WriteLine(Voornaam + " " + Achternaam + " " + Adres + " " + Salaris);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to pass the `client` object as a parameter, define the parameter type in the `print` method:

```
    public void print (client obje)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (obje.Voornaam + " " + obje.Achternaam + " " + obje.Adres + " " + obje.Salaris);
    }
```

This tells the compiler what fields/methods are available on the object.

However given that `print` is defined within `client`, there is no need to pass an object into the method.  You could just access the `client` fields directly:

```
public void print ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine (Voornaam + " " + Achternaam + " " + Adres + " " + Salaris);
    }
```